# How do I correect use a shared httpclient in .net 4.72

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient

I am using a shared httpclient to download hundreds of files in parallel.  The library is compiled for both .net 6 and .net4.72, which means that IHttpClientFactory is not available for net472.  The server I am trying to download from is behind an Azure traffic monitor and a load balancer.  This means the same URI might go to a different IP for every request.  It works most of the time, but some users are complaining their downloads hang.  As far as I can tell, this happens when the traffic manager suddenly decides to route the traffic through an entirely different region.

What I have tried:

- I have a timeout of 1 minute set on the httpclient, after which I cancel the download and get a new (non-shared) httpclient.  It tries this 5 times before giving up.
- I tried disposing of the old httpclient when one download times out (this cancels all the other downloads in progress and closes the connection)
- I tried setting the DNS refresh time to 10 seconds via the servicepoint manager.
- Adding the ip address of the server to c:\windows\system32\etc\drivers\hosts file.  This bypasses the traffic manager and load balancer and actually solves the issue.  However, this is not a workable long term solution.

I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: **Oblig:** https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Also, why are you targeting .NET 4.7.2 and not .NET 4.8.1? Every computer/OS that can run 4.7.2 can run 4.8.1.

Comment: _"which means that IHttpClientFactory is not available for net472"_ - **This is incorrect**: 
`IHttpClientFactory` is in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` NuGet package which is available for all .NET platforms.

Comment: @Dai how come msdn doesn't list any of the full frameworks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Because it’s part of the “.NET Platform Extensions” which is not part of _.NET-proper_. The platform extensions libraries are available for all major .NET platforms (including .NET Standard)